# Unable to resolve attribute in directive from root scope

Tags: angularjs

This should be easy, but I've been struggling with it.

`<progress-bar complete="5%" steps="$root.organizationSteps" current='1'></progress-bar>`

I need to add a class to `ul.steps` that's like `steps-4` if there are 4 steps, or `steps-3` if there are 3.  I can't figure out how to determine how many steps there are.  I've tried using `scope: {steps: '&'}` with no luck.

```
directive('progressBar', function () {
    return {
        scope: false,
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: function(el, attrs) {
            var html = '<div class="progressBar"><div class="contentProgress"><div></div></div>';
            if (angular.isDefined(attrs.steps)) {
                html += '<ul class="steps">';
                    html += '<li ng-repeat="step in '+attrs.steps+'" ng-class="{current: $index == '+(attrs.current-1)+'}">{{ step }}</li>';
                html += '</ul>';
            }
            return html+'</div>';
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var config = {
                    tooltip: "N",
                    color: "G"
                },
                bar = element.find('div'),
                stepEl = element.find('.steps');

            if (angular.isDefined(stepEl)) {
                stepEl.addClass("steps-"+attrs.total);
            }

            if (typeof attrs.color != 'undefined')
                config.color = attrs.color[0];

            if (typeof attrs.complete != 'undefined')
                bar.css('width', attrs.complete);

            bar
                .addClass("bar"+config.color.toUpperCase())
                .addClass('tip'+config.tooltip);
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use the `$root` reference if the element is defined on rootscope or infact on any scope. If `organizationSteps` is defined over the rootScope you can reference it anywhere by binding to variable `organizationSteps`.
This

```
 if (angular.isDefined(attrs.steps)) {
                html += '<ul class="steps">';
                    html += '<li ng-repeat="step in '+attrs.steps+'" ng-class="{current: $index == '+(attrs.current-1)+'}">{{ step }}</li>';
                html += '</ul>';
            }
```

should be

```
            html += '<ul class="steps">';
                html += '<li ng-repeat="step in organizationSteps" ng-class="{current: $index == '+(attrs.current-1)+'}">{{ step }}</li>';
            html += '</ul>';
```

If you want to use isolated scope using scope property then html should be

`<progress-bar complete="5%" steps="organizationSteps" current='1'></progress-bar>`

Your directive definition would have

`scope: {steps:'='}`

You can refer to this `steps`  variable in the repeat.